# Event System add-on in Sites 9.1 'Pending Activation"

Tags: event-system, sites-9.1

I have created an add-on for the Tridion Sites 9.1 Event System.  In the .zip Add-on package I have placed my compiled DLL and the manifest.json file.  Below is my manifest.json.

After selecting 'Upload Add-on Package' the GUI recognizes it and adds it to the add-on screen, but the status remains at 'Pending activation'.  I have tried restarting CM services but the status remains the same.  Any ideas?

```
{
  "manifestVersion": "1.0",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "demoEventSystem",
  "name": "Demo EventSystem addon",
  "author": "Robert Curlette",
  "description": "Demo Event System using add-on",
  "requireConfiguration": "No",
  "extensions": [
   {
        "name":"MyEventHandler",
        "type": "CMEventHandler",
        "properties": {
        "assemblyFileSource": "event_system_example.dll"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: For me, your configuration looks good, Can you check is there any error on the Event Viewer in the Tridion Application logs, also check in the add service logs is there any error  eg: path C:\Add-OnService\bin\logs, I assume you have registered Add On service URL during the CM install, usually for CM add extensions upload not required for services restart. I did try with your configuration with my DDL it works for me. Just to double-check Is that your .zip file name demoEventSystem.zip?

Comment: After uploading your extension try access CMS URL to see it's loading or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status will remain 'Pending Activation' until the extension (whatever it may be) is triggered. This is how the Add-on statuses are implemented, so try triggering the ES and check again. BTW. manually restarting any services for CM side extensions is not needed.

One other situation in which I've seen an extension stuck in Pending Activation was a UI extension with a faulty manifest file, but yours looks OK.